# Reporting Service web service endpoint - Could not connect to server: https://site/ReportService2005.asmx

Tags: web-services, ssrs

I'm assigned to update reports for SSRS that a coworker designed years ago who has retired.
I review the instruction he left. He created a cmd that uses [rs.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/rs-exe-utility-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) to deploy the reports.

I perform the cmd but it errors with

> Could not connect to server: https://site/ReportService2005.asmx

I figured maybe since the SSRS is updated so I tried to browse https://site/ReportService2010.asmx.
But it also doesn't seem to exist.

Is there any way to locate the correct asmx URL?
Or is it possible that there is no asmx at all? (cause other colleagues said they migrate the whole server previously)

Update

I search disk with *.asmx, didn't find ReportServiceXXXX.asmx.
The closest I found is

> C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_updateservices-webservices-reporting_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_0c518d9bcc8e98be\ReportingWebService.asmx

But I don't think this is what I'm looking for...

Comment: Have you tried to find the asmx file on the project's folder or the entire disk? If the server was migrated, have you checked on the new server?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the server hosts SSRS, open reporting service configuration manager.
Here is a tab about web service.

[image]

For my case, the URL is
https://site/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx